# Where is Visual Studio autocomplete for JQuery 1.4?

Tags: jquery, visual-studio, autocomplete, intellisense

I can't find the Visual Studio autocomplete file for JQuery 1.4.  Googling for jquery-1.4-vsdoc or jquery-1.4.min-vsdoc turns up nothing.

Comment: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/02/08/jquery-1-4-1-intellisense-with-visual-studio.aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

good answer by Nick Berardi - checking out Scott Gu's Twitter -

**

> ## @sirkirby Yes - we'll be updating the Microsoft AJAX CDN to host jQuery
>
> 1.4. We'll also have full intellisense support for it.    2:47 PM Jan 14th
>   from web  in reply to sirkirby

**

Answer (score 3):

This typically comes out 2 weeks after a new release.  Because the Visual Studio Documentation XML for JavaScript is non-standard and requires a lot of manual work to move from JSDoc to VSDoc.  Give it another week and you should see an announcement on the Gu's blog.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll find that the vsdoc-ing the jquery source is a separate exercise done by peeps working for Microsoft.  There is bound to be a lag between the releasing of jquery code and these peeps getting around to tweaking it up for intellisense in VS.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not on google it doesn't exist ;-)

According to http://code.google.com/p/jqueryjs/downloads/list latest available version with Intellisense is 1.3.2.

Comment: They moved the code to be hosted else where with this release.  http://code.jquery.com.  So Google Code doesn't seem relevant any longer.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see:

http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/cdn.ashx

The vsdoc for jquery 1.4 (or 1.4.1) is not yet ready or atleast published/linked

but in that website i'm sure you'll find it when ready

Answer (score -3):

I believe you may be looking for the [jQuery Code Snippets for Visual Studio 2010](http://john-sheehan.com/blog/jquery-snippets-for-visual-studio-2010/).

Comment: He's speaking of intellisense, not code snippets. Useful link, though... just not relevant.